# clearing concept of combination

Tags: combinations

I have $16$ categories and each category contains $10$ pages. I can only choose $1$ page from each $16$ categories. All the categories are independent of each other. so what is the possible ways to do so?

I thought of like I can choose 1 out of 10 pages in $16$ categories so it should be $10\choose 1$ multiplied $16$ times. which gives an answer $10^{16}$. so am I correct or I have completely missed the concept ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Next time it is prefered that you type in MathJax your formulars.

Comment: And yes based on the multiplication rules it is $10^{16}$

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Thank You!! and how do I type in this beautifull format?

Comment: Thank you @joriki

Answer (score 1):

It's correct.

By multiplication principle, there are $10^{16}$ possible ways.